# Avoiding type confusion with the square (or nth root etc) of some quantity in modern C++

Tags: c++

Immediately after its introduction, [these recommendations for how to program in C++](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) start with the philosophical assertion that one should **"Express ideas directly in code"**. It sounded like a great idea until I came to this:

```
Speed s;                 // there will be one single value
std::vector<Mass> m;     // there may be millions/billions of values
ComputeTotalKineticEnergy();
```

If there are lots of masses, and the normal "half-em-vee-squared" laws of physics apply, it makes sense to square the speed outside the (implicit, necessary) loop over the vector of masses. But what is the type of the `Speed s` variable once squared? Doesn't the notion of expressing ideas **"directly in code"** lead to problems the moment you want to compute a logarithm or nth root or similar? In this case, one could define an (ugly) type of `SpeedSquared`, but what is the general principle that applies equally well to functions applied to a `Speed` as to a `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`?

Comment: What would squaring a `time_point` mean. Also I think you are taking this too literally, it sounds more like a guideline than a rule.

Comment: I'm uncertain that there is a "general principle". A programmer, above all else, must be a pragmatic creature, and follow rules/guidelines only when it makes sense to do so. Following too closely to rules like Stroustrup's (I _always_ have to look up how to spell his name), without questioning why you're following them, will only ever lead you down into the pit of cargo-cult programming.

Comment: If you have two masses at the same speed, then their combined kinetic energy is `m1*v*v/2 + m2*v*v/2` (physics) which equals `(m1+m2)*v*v/2` (math). *That* is the "*idea*" that you want to "*express directly in code*".

Comment: there is no "general principle". I think definition of data types depends on your "domain model".

Comment: @M.M Oops - I guess I meant a `std::chrono::duration` but was really just looking for something long and complex. But agreed - they are guidelines... but still that means they are there for guidance. So it leaves one with the question of how to resolve the likes of squaring a speed - should one bother to define a `Speed` type at all... or just use a `double`, which these guidelines explicitly state as bad practice. If there is a general principle, I would like to know what it is.

Comment: What is `Speed` anyway? Shouldn't you rather use `MetersPerSecond` or something like that? I believe it's better to use `double` and name the variable `speed` for simplicity and readability and your idea is expressed just as well

Comment: @slawekwin: You're confusing two concepts there, a physical quantity and the units it's expressed in. As for just using a `double`, aks NASA what kind of bugs that enables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really care about having strong types for quantities, use [Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_units.html), or write your own units library.

Otherwise, just convert the `Speed` and `Mass` values to real numbers when you do the kinetic energy calculation, and then convert the resulting real number to an `Energy` value, or something. It's not a big deal that you're not using a "proper" type at one tiny intermediate stage of your calculation.

Comment: To clarify, Boost.Units understands the SI type system and maps it to the C++ type system. Physics has no problem whatsoever with `SpeedSquared`, it's just a quantity with unit `m^2 / s^2` or `J/kg`. Similarly, Boost.Units understands that squaring a quantity doubles the exponents of its units.